# How to Split DataSet in 2 to Display in Different GridViews

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, dataset

How can I split a `DataSet` in half so that each half can be bound to a seperate `GridView`?

**Currently I am doing:**

```
gridviewQc1.DataSource = SelectedQCItems;
gridviewQc1.DataBind();
```

Where `SelectedQCItems` is my `DataSet`.

**What I would like to do:**

```
gridviewQc1.DataSource = SelectedQCItemsFirstHalf;
gridviewQc1.DataBind();

gridviewQc2.DataSource = SelectedQCItemsSecondHalf;
gridviewQc2.DataBind();
```

---

I tried calling

```
var table = SelectedQCItems.Tables[0];
var halfData = table.Select().Take(table.Rows.Count/2);
gridviewQc1.DataSource = halfData;
gridviewQc1.DataBind();
```

But on the last line I get a `HttpException`

> A field or property with the name 'Criteria' was not found on the selected data source.

I guess the header names are not stored in each individual `Table` object in the `DataSet`.

Am I doing something wrong or should I appraoch this differently?

The code for the `GridView`:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridviewQc1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
    AutoGenerateSelectButton="true" OnRowDataBound="gridviewQc1_RowDataBound"
    OnSelectedIndexChanged="gridviewQc1_SelectedIndexChanged" >
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Criteria" DataField="Criteria" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Major" DataField="Major" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Mass" DataField="Mass"/>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Have you tried passing `dataset` values to `dataview` then set `dataview` as gridview's datasource?

Comment: Add a column with a autonumeric (row_number() in TSQL, you could code it) and use a DataView where you can specify a filter based on the new column

Comment: @P.Pat I have not - is `DataView` easier to split in 2?

Comment: @bradbury9 I am using an Acces Database so will have to see if that is possible here

Comment: Yes it is easier and you can use this [Dataview Filter](https://asp-net-example.blogspot.com/2011/05/how-to-use-dataview-rowfilter-property.html) as a reference on how you will eventually split your `DataSet` since as far as I know, I haven't read any direct split to half then bind each half into separate `GridView`.

Comment: @P.Pat I am trying to use `DataView` with `RowFilter`, but my rows don't appear to have an `Index` or `Id` column. When I filter with `Index='1'` I see 0 rows sand then I index with `ID='1'` I get a `Column ID does not exist` error. I think I need to filter on a `Index` based within the `DataTable` rather than the Index from the original database. I managed to split the `DataTables` manually (as seen in my answer), but I think your suggestion sounds better!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to do this with the below code, which creates 2 copies the `DataSet` and then deletes half of the entries from each copy before binding them to the 2 `GridViews`:

```
var ds1 = SelectedQCItems.Copy();
var ds2 = SelectedQCItems.Copy();

var lastRowIndex = SelectedQCItems.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1;
var halfwayIndex = SelectedQCItems.Tables[0].Rows.Count / 2 - 1;

for (int i = lastRowIndex; i > halfwayIndex; i--)
{
    ds1.Tables[0].Rows.RemoveAt(i);
}
ds1.AcceptChanges();

for (int i = halfwayIndex; i > -1; i--)
{
    ds2.Tables[0].Rows.RemoveAt(i);
}
ds2.AcceptChanges();

var one = ds1.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
var two = ds2.Tables[0].Rows.Count;

gridviewQc1.DataSource = ds1;
gridviewQc1.DataBind();

gridviewQc2.DataSource = ds2;
gridviewQc2.DataBind();
```